# $\int \frac{1}{a+bu+cu^{2}+du^{s}} du$ where $ s \in [0,2] $

Tags: calculus, integration

I've encountered an integral of the form...
$$
\int \frac{1}{a+bu+cu^{2}+du^{s}} du \ , \ s \in [0,2]
$$
My first idea to finding an aproximate form to this integral was to expand the $u^{s}$ term into it's taylor series around 1, and then take the first 3 terms as they would be constributing the most. If there are any ideas for how to solve it exactly using special functions or more exotic techniques it would be very useful. Obviously for any integer value of $s$ the integral exactly evaluates to the inverse tangent, so the general behavior is clear it only finding an expresssion for a general $s$ in the specified range is the issue. Ive also considered attempting to interpolate acrosss the different tangent solutions to find an expression in terms of $s$ that would at least evaluate too the tangent expressions for integer $s$. Any help on finding an actual expression or finding it is connected in some way to some other more well known integrals would be great.

Comment: What is known about $a,b,c,d$ ? And are you after an exact answer or an approximation, and if it's an approximation how close do you need it?

Comment: I would like to find an exact awnser if possible, but all that can be concreatly stated about the coeficents is that they are all positive and non-zero.

Comment: Could you tell in which context you faced this integral ?

Comment: I was working with some non-linear differential equations pertaining to some research Im doing on the reaction forces of fast fluid flows when encountering an obstruction.

Comment: More context would be useful. What was the background physical problem with concrete regime details and assumptions, and what kinds of bounds were on the integral? If you want an approximation this info is important. What you're asking right now could be as undefined as $\int \sin x dx \approx \int x dx$, which is clearly a terrible approximation if the bounds were say $100\pi$ to $101\pi$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Well I did say that I was looking for an exacty solution but maybe I didnt make that clear enough having only talked about the aproximative techniques I had used. If so thats my fault and Im sorry. The reason for only usuing aproximative techniques though is because I have zero clue on where to even start trying to find an exact solution.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ I think I understand what your saying but Im a little confused on how the lagrange inversion therom can generate all the possible roots of this wierd polynomial. Im also unsure as to whether polynomials with non-integer powers can be factored into monomial terms. Aswell as I dont know how many possible roots there would be with a psuo-polynomial such as this.

Comment: @AidanR.S. The factor part was a mistake, but you can substitute $x=au^s+bu^2+cu+d\implies u=f(x)$ making your integral $\int\frac{f’(x)}x dx$. You can solve for $u=f(x)$ as a series using the method on MO’s [series solution for general trinomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial). Are you sure you want all complex/real roots if we use this other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\F{\operatorname F}$
Factor and use binomial series:

$$\int\frac{du}{u^s+k(u+p)(u+q)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n k^{-n-1}  \int u^{ns} (u+p)^{-n-1} (u+q)^{-n-1}du$$

where [Appell $\F_1$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppellF1.html) appears, but switching the order of $u^s$ and $k(u+p)(u+q)$ in the binomial expansion makes the Appell function, and series, diverge. Therefore:

$$\boxed{\int\frac{du}{u^s+k(u+p)(u+q)}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{u^{ns+1}}{(ns+1)(-kpq)^{n+1}}\F_1\left(ns+1;n+1,n+1;ns+2;-\frac up,-\frac uq\right)}$$

shown here:
[image]

The result is a [triple hypergeometric series](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/9/3/93).